# Spring Cloud Stream functional Producer/Consumer

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

My application consists of a REST controller with a POST method to submit data that I had to send to a topic using a producer.

This is the controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/producer/v1")
public class ApiController {
    @Autowired
    Producer producer;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Invia un messaggio al topic", response = String.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
    @PostMapping(path = "/sendMessage", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void sendMessage(@RequestBody() @Valid MyMessage myMessage) {
        producer.produce(myMessage.getId(), myMessage);
    }
}
```

Using spring cloud stream version < 3.1
I had this producer:

```
@Component
public class Producer {
    private final ProducerChannelInterface producerChannelInterface;

    public Producer(ProducerChannelInterface producerChannelInterface) {
        this.producerChannelInterface = producerChannelInterface;
    }
    public void produce(int messageId, Object message) {
        MessageChannel messageChannel = producerChannelInterface.kafkaOutChannel();
        messageChannel.send(
                MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(message)
                        .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .setHeader(PARTITION_KEY, messageId)
                        .build()
        );
    }
}
```

From version 3.1, `@Output` and `@EnableBinding` annotations are deprecated, so I'm try to switch to the new way to setup a Producer, I'm working in this way

```
@Component
public class Producer {
    @Bean
    public Supplier<Message<Object>> produce() {
        return () -> {
            int messageId = ...;
            Object message = new MyMessage();
            return MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(message)
                .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .setHeader(PARTITION_KEY, messageId)
                .build();
        };
    }
}
```

finally in the application.yaml I have this

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        #Channel name
        produce-out-0:
          destination: spring-cloud-topic
          contentType: application/json
          producer:
            partitionKeyExpression: headers['partitionKey']
            partitionCount: 1
            errorChannelEnabled: true

...
      kafka:
        bindings:
          produce-out-0:
            producer:
              configuration:
                retries: 10
                max.in.flight.requests.per.connection: 1
                request.timeout.ms: 20000
```

The problem now is that when I start the application the method `produce()` is called infinitely (I see in the topic the messages).
Then using a supplier seems I'm forced to define the message data inside the supplier. I need to pass data from the Rest controller.

Can you help? Thanks

Comment: Just inject `StreamBridge` and use its send methods as described here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources. You don't need to use Supplier with reactive approach as described below as it is a bit more complicated for doing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

There are several 'problems' with plain SCS3 Supplier but you can resolve those. The main problem is polling. SCS will poll for messages in every seconds by default. Of course you can configure that using `DefaultPollerProperties`. But when it polls for message, you must provide one. If you can set a proper polling timeout, then you can use a queue to `offer` message and in the `Supplier` you can use `poll` on that queue.
But this isn't the proper solution, because in rest, you cannot calculate the delay between messages and you want to publish the message instantly and dont wait the maximum possible time between rest calls of course...
Better approach is using reactive streams. Thus you can emmit the message when it arrives over the rest interface, then it will be published instantly.

You can push messages into any streams using `StreamBridge`. This will push a message into the stream, but the stream must exist (same problem with non reactive streams).
You can inject it into your service and send message over the bridge.
Note that this accepts an `Object` param, so you have to provide the right type to the given stream.

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var bridge: StreamBridge
```

Then you can call

```
bridge.send("produce-out-0", messageObject)
```

Reactive Stream is better approach.

You can use the previous method with empty `Flux`. This won't emmit any messages. So you can only publish messages using the StreamBridge.

```
@Bean
public Supplier<Flux<Message<MyType>>> produce() {
    return () -> {
      Flux.empty<>()
    };
}
```

Better approach is creating a `Sink` and emmit messages through that:

```
Sinks.Many<Object> processor = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer<Object>()
```

Then you can use this as the source of the Supplier

```
@Bean
public Supplier<Flux<Message<Object>>> produce() {
    return () -> {
      processor.asFlux()
    };
}
```

And push a message into it:

```
 processor.emitNext(messageObject, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)
```